# Função com cookies em PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Preciso de uma função php que verifique se o usuário já acessou tal arquivo, se sim, abre X arquivo javascript, caso não tenha acessado, abre outro arquivo javascript.

Exemplo: 1° acesso = abrir teste.js
2° ou mais acessos = abrir ola.js

Comment: Pode postar algum código que você já tentou fazer ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um cookie no navegador do usuário quando ele acessar pela primeira vez, e depois, verificar se ele já possui tal cookie.

```
//Primeiro, verificamos se o usuário já possui o cookie
if(isset($_COOKIE['acesso'])) {

   //Se o usuário possuir o cookie no navegador, significa que já acessou a pagina
   //Então carregaremos o js ola
   echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="ola.js"></script>';

} else {

    //Se o usuário não possuir o cookie significa que nunca acessou a pagina
    //Então vamos setar o cookie, e carregar o js teste
    setcookie("acesso", 1, (time() + 100000));
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="teste.js"></script>'

}
```

Comment: Exatemente o que eu queria, valeu cara! Você consegue me explicar o porquê desse time e do "1" depois de acesso?

Comment: O 1 é porque o cookie precisa de um valor, então coloquei 1, e também porque 1 é o mesmo que true em algumas linguagens. O time() é um método PHP que retorna o [timestamp unix](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix) do exato momento que o código foi executado, então usei-o para definir o tempo de expiração do cookie, que seria 100000 segundos a partir do momento em que o cookie foi colocado (Valor do time)

Comment: Entendi, valeu!